# How to enable cache programitically?

Tags: magento-1.9, cache

Hello i want to firstly disable cache while backup & after complete it again enable cache. how to do that kindly reply me

Comment: can you check this.

Answer (score 4):

for try clear cache this

```
Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->flush();
```

**Mass action for disable for cache try**
this

```
   $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();
    $types=array('config','layout','block_html','translate','collections','eav','config_api','config_api2');

        $updatedTypes = 0;
        foreach ($types as $code) {
            if (!empty($allTypes[$code])) {
                $allTypes[$code] = 0;
                $updatedTypes++;
            }
            $tags = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($code);
        }
        if ($updatedTypes > 0) {
            Mage::app()->saveUseCache($allTypes);
        }
```

Here **$types array define type of cache**

**for enable cache:**

```
$types=array('config','layout','block_html','translate','collections','eav','config_api','config_api2');
    $allTypes = Mage::app()->useCache();

    $updatedTypes = 0;
    foreach ($types as $code) {
        if (empty($allTypes[$code])) {
            $allTypes[$code] = 1;
            $updatedTypes++;
        }
    }
    if ($updatedTypes > 0) {
        Mage::app()->saveUseCache($allTypes);
    }
```

**You can clean cache by**  `Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->cleanType($type);`
here type means:

**config Or layout Or block_html Or translate Or collections Or eav Or config_api Or config_api2**

`Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes();` this code is provide `us list of cache which is i have save in array $types.`

Comment: Nice, but instead of hard coding the cache types you can use this `$types = Mage::app()->getCacheInstance()->getTypes();`. It's safer in case you have other custom cache types.

Comment: let me check...

Comment: Please do, but so you know, this is the way the cache types are retrieved for displaying in the grid. See `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Cache_Grid::_prepareCollection`

Comment: then offsource you can used this.